# How to set timer in mootools

Tags: javascript, timer, mootools

I am trying to make a slide show in mootools, and was trying delay function to make a periodic effect in slideshow but it was not working. So i am planning to make a timer function, but have no idea how to do that.
here is something which i have done..i little messy i guess

```
function slideImages(id_new, id_old){
console.log($(id_new));
$(id_old).tween('opacity', [1,0]);
$(id_old).setStyle('display','none');
$(id_old).tween('margin-left', -980);

$(id_new).setStyle('display', 'block');
$(id_new).tween('opacity', [0,1]);
$(id_new).tween('margin-left', 180);

var c = id_new;
var d = id_old;

//timer = setInterval ( "timerFunction()", 5000 );
(slide(c, d)).delay(5000);  //this isn't working and browser is getting hanged 
}

function slide(c, d){
    console.log(c);

    if (c.split('_')[1].toInt() > 2){
        id_new = 'image_'+ 0 ;
        console.log(id_new);
    }
    else{
        id_new = 'image_'+ (c.split('_')[1].toInt()+1);
        console.log(id_new);
    }
    id_old = c;
    slideImages(id_new, id_old);
};
```

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far? It is a bit hard to understand the question otherwise. In javscript timers are usually created with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Comment: use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` they are javascript function works in all framweorks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to use delay or setTimeout. here they are:

```
function slideImages(id_new, id_old) {
    var c = $(id_new);
    var d = $(id_old);

    d.tween('opacity', [1, 0]);
    d.setStyle('display', 'none');
    d.tween('margin-left', -980);

    c.setStyle('display', 'block');
    c.tween('opacity', [0, 1]);
    c.tween('margin-left', 180);

    // your timer becomes global here, careful. crappy pattern.
    // use a closure so it goes in the upper scope, allowing you to stop.
    // cancel by clearTimeout(timer)

    // pass function to delay, scope = null, arguments
    timer = slide.delay(5000, null, [c, d]);
    // or
    timer = (function() {
        slide(c, d);
    }).delay(5000);

    // or normal js
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        slide(c, d);
    }, 5000);
}

function slide(c, d) {

    if (c.split('_')[1].toInt() > 2) {
        id_new = 'image_' + 0;
        console.log(id_new);
    }
    else {
        id_new = 'image_' + (c.split('_')[1].toInt() + 1);
        console.log(id_new);
    }
    id_old = c;
    slideImages(id_new, id_old);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i've adapted this mootools diver scroller. at the moment you have to click the buttons to move left to right. I was wondering if any one could help me put a automated scroll in?

Check with this **[Link](http://docs111.mootools.net/)**...

Also refer this code...

heres the js code

```
var totalImages = 3;
 var currentImage = 1;
 function workSlide(way) {
 var currentAmount=$("holder2").getStyle("margin-left");
 var myFx = new Fx.Tween('holder2',{duration: 600});
 if(way == "right") {
 if (currentImage <= totalImages-1) {
 currentImage++;
 var whichAmount = -(((currentImage-1)) * 920);
 myFx.start('margin-left',currentAmount,whichAmount);
 }
 } else {
 if (currentImage > 1) {
 currentImage--;
 var whichAmount = -(((currentImage-1)) * 920);
 myFx.start('margin-left',currentAmount,whichAmount);
 }
 }
 }
```